# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, qt, selenium-webdriver

We are running a browser based on webkit. I’m trying to setup a test automation environment using Selenium with Eclipse.

I have issues when running my browser and I get the message below.
I’m wondering whether I pass sufficient parameters to the call “StartSession” from the DriverService.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'

```
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)

  at ing.openqa.selenium.remote.SimpleBrowserDriver.startSession(SimpleBrowserDriver.java:200)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)

  at ing.openqa.selenium.remote.SimpleBrowserDriver.<init>(SimpleBrowserDriver.java:171)

  at ing.openqa.selenium.remote.SimpleBrowserDriver.<init>(SimpleBrowserDriver.java:137)

  at ing.openqa.selenium.remote.SimpleBrowserDriver.<init>(SimpleBrowserDriver.java:110)

  at ing.openqa.selenium.remote.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.

```
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)

  ... 8 more



  at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)

  ... 10 more
```

Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

```
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)

  at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)

  ... 11 more
```

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

```
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)

  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)

  ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your WebKit-based browser supply a driver implementation? In particular, does it provide an implementation that starts an HTTP server that speaks WebDriver's JSON-over-HTTP wire protocol? If not, there's nothing for `RemoteWebDriver` to connect to and communicate with.

Comment: thanks for your answer, our browser using json well-HTTP protocol, for now i try to working on the selenium driver that should enable me to use it selenium for my future tests.